# Heroku + PHP + Doctrine 2

Tags: php, heroku, doctrine-orm

I've got a free app in Heroku which I've developed locally with MySQL + PHP + Doctrine. The next step is create the PostgreSQL database schema with Doctrine.

I created the schema locally with the command "php -f doctrine.php orm:schema-tool:create" and I thought that I could execute it from the server in a PHP script like this "exec("php -f doctrine.php orm:schema-tool:create");". But, unfortunately the database schema hasn't been created. So my questions is "How I can create the database schema in Heroku with Doctrine?".

I've got some other problems like "How I know what's the db encoding? i.e. UTF-8 and how to change it?" To be honest, I'm finding difficult to work on Heroku and I'd like to know if there is documentation referred to Heroku + PHP + Doctrine or if someone has come across with a similar project and could give me some advice to deploy the app successfully.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this Doctrine DBAL or the ORM?